# On the n-th derivative of the inverse function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Given a function $f(x)$, its inverse $g(x)$ is defined as $g(f(x)) \equiv x$.

In light of this, the *n-th derivative of $g(x)$* can be recursively calculated as follows:

```
list = {};

For[n = 1, n <= 6, n++,

    eqn = D[g[f[x]], {x, n}] == D[x, {x, n}];
    var = Derivative[n][g][f[x]];

    If[n == 1,
       list = Join[list, Solve[eqn, var][[1]]],
       list = Join[list, (Solve[eqn, var] /. list)[[1]]]
      ]

   ]

list // Expand // TableForm
```

[image]

In MMA you can get this very simply by writing something like this:

```
Derivative[n][InverseFunction[f]][f[x]]
```

**The question that arises is the following**: *is the latter formulation using a recursive process like the one shown above or is there a non-recursive formulation?*

Comment: Something like `Derivative[3][InverseFunction[f]][f[x]]`?

Comment: Sounds like a math question, not Mathematica ... (it's interesting though)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
D[InverseFunction[f][x], {x, 6}]
```

Towards the question whether this is computed recursively: I guess so from analyzing the `Trace` produced by executing the code:

```
Table[
 Length@Trace[
   D[InverseFunction[f][x], {x, k}]
   ],
 {k, 1, 12}]
```

> {6, 7, 7, 10, 13, 18, 25, 36, 51, 73, 103, 145}

Answer (score 5):

In fact, there is a closed-form expression for the derivatives of an inverse function, if one is willing to use the [(partial) Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) (implemented in *Mathematica* as `BellY[]`). This is related to the [Lagrangian inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) (and see also the discussion in [Charalambides](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=PDMGA-v5G54C&pg=PA433)).

```
inverseD[ff_, x_] := inverseD[ff, {x, 1}]

inverseD[ff_, {x_, k_Integer?NonNegative}] := With[{f = Function[x, ff]},

       If[k == 0, Return[InverseFunction[f][x]]];
       If[k == 1, Return[1/f'[InverseFunction[f][x]]]];

       With[{ifun = InverseFunction[f][x]},
            BellY[Table[{(k + j - 2)!, -Derivative[j][f][ifun]/f'[ifun]/j},
                        {j, 2, k}]]/((k - 1)! f'[ifun]^k)]]
```

For example:

```
(inverseD[g[t], {t, 4}] == D[InverseFunction[g][t], {t, 4}] /. Function[t, g[t]] -> g) // Simplify
```

Comment: (I'm still computer-less, but I had this as a draft blog post, so I thought I'd post it.)

Comment: It is always amazing with what you come up. Good to hear from you by the way!