# Can I use inbuilt machine learning to guess the n-th term of the inverse series?

Tags: series-expansion, machine-learning

Consider this concrete example.

```
InverseSeries[ Series[ PolyLog[s, z], {z, 0, 10}]]
```

From this output is there a way of writing down a formula for the n-th term? I mean can I guess all the other terms beyond what is being displayed using machine learning subroutines or whatever.

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction` is pretty powerful for this sort of pattern search.

Comment: There is no need to guess. You can always construct the [Lagrangian inversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166103) of a series.

Comment: Ok J.M. thanks. I did the Lagrange inversion and got a whole bunch of coefficients called g(n). I can list them one by one for the PolyLog[3/2,z] function but I really need some way of guessing a closed form of the n-th term in terms of some managable function of n.

Comment: Here are the first 6 g(n)'s for PolyLog[3/2,z] inversion as per wiki notation. Seventh term onwards is taking forever: {1,-(1/Sqrt[2]),3/2-2/Sqrt[3],-3+10 Sqrt[2/3]-15/(2 Sqrt[2]),475/12+45/Sqrt[2]-35 Sqrt[3]-24/Sqrt[5],-315+252 Sqrt[2/5]-7315/(12 Sqrt[2])+70 Sqrt[3]+190 Sqrt[6]}